# Properly define the members and invariants of a class in R

Tags: r

We have an R package for a certain purpose. The basic data structure is a *correlation function* which is a real/complex valued function for a smallish (100) number (T) of time slices. We have multiple measurements (N) of it, so at its core it is a N×T matrix. But then there are more things that it can become:

- One can bootstrap it with R samples such that it becomes an R×T matrix. However we want to keep the original data, so there is a field for the R×T matrix and another for the N×T matrix.
- It can be *symmetrized* which will cut T in half and also alter various other functions that work with those objects.
- Also it can be *shifted* which takes the difference between consecutive elements and therefore drops one time slice. The first column in the matrix then corresponds to `t = 1` and not `t = 0` any more, which becomes important in fits to the data.
- Correlation functions may have an imaginary part, this is stored as a second real matrix. But they might not.
- When doing non-linear operations with the data, we do that once with the average of the original data and each bootstrap sample. If the result is another correlation function, that object will not have “original data” but only the average.

So basically we have a class that can have various fields and only the average of the original data is really common.

To make things worse, there is no formal documentation for the possible members and the invariants associated with them. Coming from C++ where a concise class definition allows me do encapsulation, The S3 class system in R seems like an invitation for inconsistencies.

This surfaced a few times when some function taking such a correlation function as argument and expected some field to be present while it was not. The code is riddled with lines that just add another field to the class when performing an operation.

Long story short: Is there some automatically enforcable way in the S3 class system to have an exhaustive list of all the fields that a class can have? Right now I only see the possibility to document (in English) in the constructor function and just hope nobody missed a line where fields were added.

Comment: [R6 classes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html) are really nice + straightforward. They're also lockable, which you might be able to use to enforce the restriction you need? Just a thought ~~

Comment: I had not thought about a more modern class system, though I am aware that there is at least also S4. The library was started 10 years ago, so perhaps the S3 system was the only one then. — We have a bunch of code using the library, so changing the most important data structure to another class system might break everything, I'll have to take a look into the R6 class system. We need to debate in the team whether to invest that effort.

Comment: Sounds sensible, best of luck :p